# Local wamp server not accessible

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have a wamp server on my laptop. I've managed to access it from anoter laptop/mobile, but since yesterday it doesn't work anymore. I can access the server locally, but not from another laptop, on a local network.

I have yet in my http.conf :

```
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from all
```

Comment: Can your devices ping each other?

Comment: Hm, have you tried restarting your WAMP services? What is the HTTP error you receive when attempting to connect using a remote device?

Comment: Yes I restarted it. There is no error, the page just keep loading

Comment: OK, try the following. Open http.conf and add the following lines to the bottom: `AcceptFilter http none` and `AcceptFilter https none`. With a line break in-between, of course. Restart WAMP. Try again.

Comment: Doesn't work. I change to xampp, it seems to work with it !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing that syntax to

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

If you dont actually want to allow from absolutely anywhere, including the internet, you could try being a little more secure with your `allows` and use :-

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
Allow from 192.168
```

This `Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1` covers all local addresses i.e. the machine running Apache.

This `Allow from 192.168` covers any ip in your local (internal) network.

If you are using Apache 2.4.x there is also a new, and in my opinion easier to read syntax.

Replace this

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

with:-

```
Require all granted
```

Or replace this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
Allow from 192.168
```

with :-

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168
```